# Sliding Hidden Node

Tags: animation, javafx

I have a question.

**My question**

How do I make the rectangle hide under the button when it slides. I do not want it to come out of the other side of the button.

```
package javafxapplication24;

import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

/**
 *
 * @author phili_000
 */
public class JavaFXApplication24 extends Application {
    public    Button by;
      
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    
  FlowPane root = new FlowPane( );
  root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
  Button butt = new Button("Play");
  Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(200,40);
 
     rect.setFill(Color.VIOLET);
     
  TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(6000),rect);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,700,700);
      
        transition.setToX(-300);
 
        root.getChildren().addAll(butt,rect);
       butt.setOnAction((event) -> {
   transition.play();
});
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
              
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
}
```

I tried my best explaining, but if you have any questions. Or comment on how I can improve my questions. Please, don't hesitate to click that 'add comment' button and give me your ideas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Z-Order in JavafFX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988196/z-order-in-javaffx)

Comment: @Fabian I am not sure how to use toBack or toFront

Comment: Here you shouldn't do it; however `FlowPane` is an layout that is ill suited for such animations and maybe you should change that first...

Answer (score 0):

Add the rectangle first, then the button:

```
root.getChildren().addAll(text, butt);
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer it did solve another problem I had. But I need the rectangle to not come out of the other side the button. Your answer made the rectangle slide under the button which is great!. I want it to  be visible only when it slides out.