# how to use view order in set style javafx?

Tags: css, javafx

i'm struggling with a vertical box i added a transition to, it stays at the back of the other nodes like label and imageview. i tried using toFront() but it didn't work. also i tried using .setStyle("-fx-view-order: [number]") but i was lost a bit in what the numbers represent exactly is it the order of nodes ascending or descending.

---

#1

```
vb.setStyle("-fx-view-order: 0");

img.setStyle("-fx-view-order: 1");
```

didn't work

#2

```
vb.setStyle("-fx-view-order: 1");

img.setStyle("-fx-view-order: 0");
```

didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get a Node to render on top is to move it to the end of the child node list for its parent Node.

Note the documentation for -fx-view-order mentions: "The parent traverses its children in decreasing viewOrder order."    To me that means higher view order is behind (drawn first) relative to lower view order.  However, this is all relative to the parent node, not the Scene.  Give us a reproducible example of what you are doing.

Also, what version of JavaFX are you using?  -fx-view-order was not in JavaFX 8 (JDK 8)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#node

Comment: "_The easiest way to get a Node to render on top is to move it to the end of the child node list for its parent Node_" – That depends. If your nodes are in a layout which positions them based on their order in the children list, changing the order of the list can have undesired effects. Also, note that JavaFX 2.X was during the Java 7 era. The version number of Java and JavaFX have been mirroring each other since Java 8.

Comment: right!! that worked. thank you i didn't think of putting it at the end of the child nodes list. i'm using jdk 8 so maybe thats why it didn't work with me

Comment: @user9910282 If this answer solved your issue, you should mark it correct.

Comment: @Slaw Yes, right about the FX version. I've updated the answer.  You are also right about potential side-effects of moving the child node in the list, however in most cases when that matters the layout would avoid overlapping nodes as well, so it isn't likely to apply.

Comment: That's true, regarding layouts typically not overlapping their children, but all bets are off once you start transforming the child nodes. For instance, maybe you want to do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51071095/javafx-css-move-node-to-front/51071882#51071882). In that example, changing the order of the children would mess everything up (or at least make the implementation much more difficult). I only bring this up because the OP mentioned "transition".

Comment: Where is the documentation for `-fx-view-order`, could you link to it?

Comment: @jewelsea The CSS property is documented [here](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#node). And the corresponding JavaFX property is documented [here](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#viewOrderProperty()).