# JavaFX 3d SubScene in 2d Scene

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm developing a GUI for a game and I want to mix a 3D SubScene with a 2D Pane in JavaFX. I have a group called root3D that contains all my 3d objects already set correctly, and then I'm creating a Pane using an FXML file set through JavaFX Scene Builder. But nothing shows up and I can only see my 3D Objects.

```
       PerspectiveCamera camera = new PerspectiveCamera(true);
       camera.setTranslateZ(-30);
       Group root3D = new Group(model1,model2,model3); //various 3d models I imported
       SubScene subScene = new SubScene(root3D, 1280, 700, true,SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
       subScene.setCamera(camera);
       FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/file.fxml"));
       AnchorPane pane = loader.load();
       pane.getChildren().add(subScene);
       Scene scene = new Scene(pane);
       primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       primaryStage.setResizable(false);
       primaryStage.show();
```

FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <ImageView fitHeight="214.0" fitWidth="169.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
               <image>
                  <Image url="@../Sprite/Cards/Small/podium-characters-Poseidon.png" />
               </image>
            </ImageView>
            <TextField prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="274.0" text="APOLLO">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Trebuchet MS Bold Italic" size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </TextField>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

[image: No sign of the FXML Layout]

EDIT: I found out that resizing the subscene, I can see the FXML elements. Apparently they are being "covered" by the subscene. Does anyone know how to lay the FXML elements on top of the subscene and not the opposite like it's happening now?
[image: The Subscene covers the FXML Layout I created]

Comment: See [Z-Order in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988196/z-order-in-javafx). Unfortunately, you don't appear to provide enough information for me to be more specific. Consider providing a [mre] if you need more help. You may want to check out `StackPane` as well. Also, from your call to `pane.setCenter(subScene)` I assume that `pane` references a `BorderPane`. If that's correct then you should remove the call to `pane.getChildren().add(subScene)`. When it comes to layouts such as `BorderPane` you should not interact with the children list directly.

Comment: Make sure your FXML root node is either an `HBox` or a `BorderPane`.  `BorderPane` is probably preferred. Set the `Subcene to the `center` or `right`.

Comment: apparently I edited the question but some edits didn't show up so the code was a mix between the two and got me confused as well. I fixed it. My FXML root is an Anchor Pane at the moment; is that the problem Sedrick? I tried to make it a StackPane but the result seems the same.

Comment: BorderPane would not have worked. From your image, I thought you had a panel on the left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you've found a solution, I'm posting an answer with the hope of making things a little clearer with regards to *why* calling `toBack()` on your `SubScene` works.

### Z-Order

Each `Parent`, which all layouts inherit from, can have one or more children. If two (or more) children occupy the same space within the `Parent` then one will be rendered on top of the other. Which child is drawn over the other is determined by two things:

1. The order of the children in the `Parent`'s [children list](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Parent.html#getChildren()).
2. (Since JavaFX 9) The value of each child's [`viewOrder`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#viewOrderProperty()) property relative to the other children in the same `Parent`.

The [Z-Order in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988196/z-order-in-javafx) Q&A goes into more detail.

### The Problem in Your Code

Your FXML file describes an `AnchorPane` which has a `StackPane` as its only child. This means that the following:

```java
AnchorPane pane = loader.load();
```

Gives you an `AnchorPane` with a `StackPane` in its children list, at the zeroth index. Then you immediately add your `SubScene` using:

```java
pane.getChildren().add(subScene);
```

The `add` method you use *appends* the element to the end of the list. So that means the `AnchorPane`'s children list's order is:

1. `StackPane`
2. `SubScene`

Since the `SubScene` comes after the `StackPane` the former is rendered on top of the latter.

### Your Solution

The solution you chose is to call `toBack()` on your `SubScene` after adding it to the `AnchorPane`. Here's [the documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#toBack()) of that method:

> Moves this `Node` to the back of its sibling nodes in terms of z-order. This is accomplished by moving this `Node` to the first position in its parent's content `ObservableList`. This function has no effect if this `Node` is not part of a group.

In other words, after you call that method the `AnchorPane`'s children list's order becomes:

1. `SubScene`
2. `StackPane`

That's why the `SubScene` is now rendered underneath the `StackPane`, because you changed the order of the children.

Note that the `toBack()` method is part of the `Node` class, not `SubScene`. The latter inherits from the former. I bring this up to point out that the problem you were having is not specific to `SubScene` or even mixing 2D and 3D scene graphs together. Both your `StackPane` and your `SubScene` are part of a 2D `Scene` (i.e. no depth buffering) which means their z-order is solely governed by what's discussed above<sup>*</sup>. The fact that the `SubScene` is 3D (i.e. depth buffering enabled) is irrelevant to the problem at hand; that fact only affects the *descendants* of said `SubScene`.

<sup>** In a 3D scene the z-coordinate of a node becomes relevant.*</sup>

### Other Solutions

Here are some other approaches that could be used to solve your problem:

- Add the `SubScene` to the start of the `AnchorPane`'s children list:

  ```java
  pane.getChildren().add(0, subScene);
  ```
- If you're using JavaFX 9+, set the `viewOrder` property of the `SubScene` to something less than that of the `AnchorPane`'s property (by default, that property's value is `0`):

  ```java
  subScene.setViewOrder(-1);
  ```
- Define your `SubScene` in the FXML file before the `StackPane` (note this approach requires the use of [an FXML controller](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers)):

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  <?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
  <?import javafx.scene.Group?>
  <?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
  <?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
  <?import javafx.scene.SceneAntialiasing?>
  <?import javafx.scene.SubScene?>
  <?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

  <AnchorPane prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1200.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1"
              xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>

      <!-- Define the SubScene before the StackPane -->
      <SubScene fx:id="subScene" width="1280" height="700" depthBuffer="true">
        <antiAliasing>
          <SceneAntialiasing fx:constant="BALANCED"/>
        </antiAliasing>

        <!-- 
          Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, you can't set your PerspectiveCamera in FXML because you
          want 'fixedEyeAtCameraZero' to be true. That property can only be set during construction but
          the constructor with that parameter does not annotate said parameter with @NamedArg, thus the
          FXMLLoader can't see it. And the no-arg constructor sets the value to false, not true. This
          means you have to inject the SubScene into your controller and add the PerspectiveCamera in
          code.
         -->

        <root>
          <!-- Inject the root into the controller in order to add your models to it in code -->
          <Group fx:id="root3D"/>
        </root>
      </SubScene>

      <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0">
        <children>
          <ImageView fitHeight="214.0" fitWidth="169.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
            <image>
              <Image url="@../Sprite/Cards/Small/podium-characters-Poseidon.png"/>
            </image>
          </ImageView>
          <TextField prefHeight="62.0" prefWidth="274.0" text="APOLLO">
            <font>
              <Font name="Trebuchet MS Bold Italic" size="22.0"/>
            </font>
          </TextField>
        </children>
      </StackPane>

    </children>
  </AnchorPane>
  ```

Answer (score 3):

As @Slaw indirectly pointed out, what I needed was to set Subscene.toBack() to set a correct Z-order in my scene. Thank you very much! While reading about Subscenes I didn't find anything about it so I hope this can help some 3d beginner in the future.
[image: final result]