# JavaFX TranslateTransition

Tags: javafx, imageview, stackpanel, translate-animation, gridpane

i have a problem with the Translate Transitions. I have a GridPane 7x7. In each cell there is a StackPane. Each StackPane has 3 ImageViews. If i want to change the position of the last added ImageView with a Translate Transition it moves but it moves under the other ImageViews. What do i have to do to keep it up top while the animation is running? It actually stays above if the animation goes up or left but not down and right.

```
TranslateTransition translate = new TranslateTransition(new Duration(animation_duration));
        translate.setToX(100);
        translate.setByY(100);

        translate.setNode(players[old_x][old_y]);
        translate.play();
```

Thanks

Comment: [mcve] please .. and stick to java naming conventions when showing code publicly

Comment: Call `players[oldX][oldY].toFront()` before starting the animation.

Comment: Note that @James solution will probably work for some layouts (e.g. `GridPane`, `StackPane`, etc.) where the order of the children don't determine their position. But be careful if you're using a layout where the order of children actually do determine their position (e.g. `HBox`, `VBox`, etc.). In those cases it would be better to manipulate the `Node.viewOrder` property (JavaFX 9+). For more information, see all the answers to [Z-Order in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988196/z-order-in-javafx).