# How to make a rectangle appear before another rectangle in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have a javafx application that I want to write and let's assume it has two rectangles on its scene and we are able to move these rectangles. My problem is that I want to write the program in a way that the image of the first rectangle always appears before the second one.

I mean that in the case that the two rectangles overlap, we always see the image of the second rectangle on the front. ( We see the second rectangle as a complete rectangle and the first one is a rectangle a part of which is not seen because of the overlap. ) and I always want the second rectangle on the front.

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm a bit familiar with javaFx and it simply sounds like you either need to render you rectangle that will overlap last, or that u change the z-index. I suggest you take a look at this question here:
[Z-Order in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988196/z-order-in-javafx)

I would have posted this as a comment but I do not have 50 rep...